# How to remap/rebind the ctrl+backspace function to shift+backspace

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

My laptop is set up so that ctrl+backspace is the key combination to delete an entire word left of the cursor. I would like to change it so that shift+backspace accomplishes this, but the guides I've found require accessing settings that are not visible on my computer.

I use Windows 10 and am fine with downloading a third-party to accomplish this.

Comment: These keys are program specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will map
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>
to
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>:

```
^Backspace::Send, +{Backspace}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: I have downloaded AutoHotKey and followed the steps provided. It has done something, as ctrl+backspace no longer deletes the entire word, just one letter, but shift+backspace does the same. How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Putting in +Backspace::Send, ^{Backspace} accomplished what I needed. Thanks for the program

Answer (score 0):

You may use download and install the "Microsoft PowerToys" app which is in [Microsoft Store](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/microsoft-powertoys/XP89DCGQ3K6VLD), there is "Keyboard Manager" in the application. There is a "Shortcuts" section in that menu, from there you may define any shortcut you like.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).